# GWT - implement ClickHandler event on a row of a FlexTable

Tags: gwt, flextable

So my software is displaying a flextable (the data is grabbed and displayed from a database) with users allowing to click on a checkbox to select a data.

```
//users is the flextable object.
userCheck = new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            CheckBox src = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
            for (int i = 1, n = users.getRowCount(); i < n; i++) {
                CheckBox box = (CheckBox) users.getWidget(i, 0);

                if (!box.equals(src)) {
                    box.setValue(false, false);
                }
            }
            removeUserButton.setEnabled(src.getValue());
            editUserButton.setEnabled(src.getValue());

        }
    };
```

The code above works, but now I'm trying to implement an action where instead of the user clicking on the checkbox, I want the user to click on a row (which ever cell of the table) and make the whole row (where the user have selected) to be highlighted. So I implemented this code below but so far it doesn't work (like the mouseclick won't register, I've yet to implement the color stuff yet.. :( ). Any suggestions?

```
userRowCheck = new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Cell src = users.getCellForEvent(event);
            int rowIndex = src.getRowIndex();
            System.out.println("Cell Selected: userRowCheck Handler, rowIndex: " + rowIndex);
            //This is just to check if this method is even called out. And well, it doesn't.
        }
    };
```

Thanks very much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added `userRowCheck` to the FlexTable : `myFlexTable.addClickHandler(userRowCheck);` it should work. Just make sure you test `src` for `null`, because if you didn't put a widget in a cell and the user clicks on that cell it returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the users.addClickHandler(userRowCheck); but if I do add that, the program freezes when I try to open up the flextable..... Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'open' (add data? or click?), but it could depend on the browser, FlexTable is known to be slow on certain browsers (i.e. IE). You could try using a Grid just to check if it is indeed the FlexTable speed.